# Linq select common subset of nested lists

Tags: c#, linq

I'll begin with my data structure.

```
class Device
{
   public List<string> Interfaces { get; set; }
}

List<Device> allDevices;
```

I would like to use Linq query to select all interfaces (strings) that are present in each device in allDevices list.

Thanks in adavance.

UPDATE:
Thanks to Aron I managed to resolve this issue.
Here's my solution:

```
List<string> commonInterfaces = allDevices.Select(device => device.Interfaces)
   .Cast<IEnumerable<string>>()
   .Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: You only want to select the `Interfaces` values that exist in all `Devices`?

Comment: @RichardDalton yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The `.AsEnumerable()` method is cleaner than the cast...sorry! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var allInterfaces = from device in allDevices
                    from interface in device.Interfaces
                    select interface;

var allInterfaces = allDevices.SelectMany(device => device.Interfaces);
```

and if Richard Dalton is correct

```
var allCommonInterfaces = allDevices
              .Select(device => device.Interfaces.AsEnumerable())
              .Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);
```

For fun...here is a more 'Optimal' solution.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CommonSubset<T>
          (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences, 
           EqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (sequences == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequences");


    Enumerator<T> enumerator = sequences.GetEnumerator();
    if(enumerator.GetNext() == false)
        throw new ArgumentException("Sequences must not be empty", "sequences");


    IEnumerable<T> first = enumerator.Current;
    HashSet<T> commonSubset = new HashSet<T>(first);
    while(enumerator.GetNext())
    {
        var nextSequence = enumerator.Current;
        var toRemove = commonSubset.Except(nextSequence, comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default).ToList();
        foreach(var r in toRemove)
            commonSubset.Remove(r);
    }
    return commonSubset;
}
```

Comment: Aggregate seems to be way to go, however it doesn't compile.
This is the error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect<string>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>)' has the wrong return type

Comment: I managed to fix this error. Posting my solution to the question itself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Whoops...List<string> vs IEnumerable<string> I should really try to compile my answers...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Enumerable.Intersect`, for example:

```
IEnumerable<string> commonSubset = allDevices.First().Interfaces;
foreach (var interfaces in allDevices.Skip(1).Select(d => d.Interfaces))
{
    commonSubset = commonSubset.Intersect(interfaces);
    if (!commonSubset.Any())
        break;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Jbj8Uk)</kbd>

If you want to reuse it you could make it an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CommonSubset<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    return CommonSubset(sequences,  EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> CommonSubset<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences, EqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (sequences == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequences");
    if (!sequences.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("Sequences must not be empty", "sequences");

    IEnumerable<T> commonSubset = sequences.First();
    foreach (var sequence in sequences.Skip(1))
    {
        commonSubset = commonSubset.Intersect(sequence, comparer);
        if (!commonSubset.Any())
            break;
    }
    return commonSubset;
}
```

Now the usage is pretty simple(the comparer can be used for custom types):

```
var allInterfaces = allDevices.Select(d => d.Interfaces);
var commonInterfaces = allInterfaces.CommonSubset();
Console.Write(string.Join(",", commonInterfaces));
```

Comment: Wow thank's for the effort even making a demo. I agree that using foreach maybe is optimized solution, however Aron's answer is simpler and answers my question exactly.

Comment: @sidon: Added an extension method for readability and convenience which works with any types ;)

Comment: Actually. The optimal solution (where m and n are large) would be to use `var commonSubset = new HashSet<T>(sequences.First())`. Then use  remove on that. You have to be careful. Some IEnumerables are very inefficient when using `GetEnumerator()` twice. So again for efficiency I would only call that once...and roll your own, `TakeOneAndSkipOne(out T, out IEnumerable<T>)` method.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for:

```
List<string> allInterfaces = allDevices.SelectMany(r=> r.Interfaces).ToList();
```

or you can select `IEnumerable<string>` like:

```
var allInterfaces =  allDevices.SelectMany(r=> r.Interfaces);
```